# Parameterize DocumentDB query with IN clause

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have a query somewhat like the following which I'm trying to parameterize:

```
List<string> poiIDs = /*List of poi ids*/;
List<string> parameterNames = /*List of parameter names*/;

string inClause = string.Join(",", parameterNames);

string query = string.Format("SELECT c.id AS poiID, c.poiName, c.latitude, c.longitude FROM c WHERE c.clusterName = @clusterName AND c.id IN ({0}) AND c.deleted = false", inClause);

IQueryable<POI> queryResult = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<POI>(Collection.SelfLink, new SqlQuerySpec
            {
                QueryText = query,
                Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection()
                {
                    new SqlParameter("@clusterName", "POI"),
                    // How do I declare the dynamically generated parameters here
                    // as new SqlParameter()?
                }
             });
```

How do I declare the dynamically generated parameters as new SqlParameter() for the Parameters property of SqlQuerySpec in order to create my document query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause ?

Comment: Appreciate your response, but I'm working with Azure DocumentDB not SQLServer.

Answer (score 3):

You can create dynamic parameterized query like this:

```
// DocumentDB query 
 // POINT TO PONDER: create the formatted query, so that after creating the   dynamic query we'll replace it with dynamically created "SQL Parameter/s"
            var queryText = @"SELECT
                                us.id,
                                us.email,           
                                us.status,
                                us.role
                            FROM user us
                            WHERE us.status = @userStatus AND us.email IN ({0})";


            // contain's list of emails  
            IList<string> emailIds = new List<string>();
            emailIds.Add("a@gmail.com");
            emailIds.Add("b@gmail.com");

            #region Prepare the query

            // simple parameter: e.g. check the user status
            var userStatus = "active";
            var sqlParameterCollection = new SqlParameterCollection { new SqlParameter("@userStatus", userStatus) };                

            // IN clause: with list of parameters:
            // first: use a list (or array) of string, to keep  the names of parameter          
            // second: loop through the list of input parameters ()
            var namedParameters = new List<string>();
            var loopIndex = 0;

            foreach (var email in emailIds)
            {
                var paramName = "@namedParam_" + loopIndex;
                namedParameters.Add(paramName);

                var newSqlParamter = new SqlParameter(paramName, email);
                sqlParameterCollection.Add(newSqlParamter);

                loopIndex++;
            }

            // now format the query, pass the list of parameter into that
            if (namedParameters.Count > 0)
                queryText = string.Format(queryText, string.Join(" , ", namedParameters));

                // after this step your query is something like this  
                // SELECT
                //                 us.id,
                //                 us.email,            
                //                 us.status,
                //                 us.role
                //             FROM user us
                //             WHERE us.status = @userStatus AND us.email IN (@namedParam_0, @namedParam_1, @namedParam_2)

            #endregion //Prepare the query

            // now inject the parameter collection object & query
            var users = Client.CreateDocumentQuery<Users>(CollectionUri, new SqlQuerySpec
            {
                QueryText = queryText,
                Parameters = sqlParameterCollection
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

The following gives you a SQL query, you can then run in your DocumentDB Collection, to get the Documents by their IDs.

```
var query = $"SELECT * FROM p WHERE p.id IN ('{string.Join("', '", arrayOfIds)}')";
```

Comment: Just add some explanation to your snippet and explain what you are doing ;)

Comment: Was in hurry and just had the "answer" in a clipboard ;). Done.

Comment: No hating, I just reviewed some answers :)

Answer (score 0):

The DocumentDB SDK doesn't support parameterized `IN` queries.

Judging from the [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause) in the comment above, SQL does not either. As mentioned in the other thread, you can use LINQ as a workaround.

Comment: You can parameterize a SQL query with IN clause. Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause

Comment: My understanding is that using LINQ instead does not help the cause against SQL Injection problem. Does it?

Comment: According to the thread you linked, SQL does not support parameterized IN as an out-of-box feature. The answers in the thread are generic workarounds and can be adapted to DocumentDB as well.

Comment: Try adapting http://stackoverflow.com/a/337792/319795 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/380185/319795

Comment: The Count of parameterNames is unknown to me for they are populated at run-time depending upon the user-input. Therefore I cannot declare the SQLParameters in the SQLParameterCollection while creating my query. I want to know whether the Query can be tweaked in a similar manner done as in the thread I posted in my comment. If yes, please post a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the ArrayContains method?  Here is an example in node

```
sqlQuery = {
        query: 'SELECT * FROM t WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(@idList, t.id)',
        parameters: [
            {
                name: '@idList',
                value: ['id1','id2','id3'],
            },
        ],
    };
```